# XAMPP on Windows 7. Htdocs folder seems to be read-only

Tags: php, windows-7, xampp, zend-studio

I'm trying to create a project on Zend Studio, but when I execute it I get a response from apache telling me that the .php file I've been editing,.. well it's not there. The project seems to be locked, because htdocs is readonly. I change that but every time I open to check the folder properties I find it as read only again. I've tried with ZendServer but it's the same thing.

Has anyone ever had similar problems? How do I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  This is kind of a [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) question... you might try asking there.  My XAMPP htdocs works fine and is writable in Win7, with an all-defaults install.

Comment: Folder "htdocs" SHOULD be read-only. If your application, deployed into this folder, should have a writeable right, it should have them limited to one, selected folder, or at least to an application folder only. I was told that htdocs should be kept read-only as a standard security procedure.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, even XAMPP control panel could not save the configuration, but I found, in the Properties, in the Security tab, the groups or user names only have Everyone and Administrators groups, and Everyone got Read only. I had to add "Authenticated Users" and provide Write permission.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have put the Xamp in a protected directory. There are two ways I can think of. Take the backup of the project first though

1. Reinstall Xampp and put it under non protected directly like C:/Xampp
2. Start the Xampp as an administrator. Right Click on Xampp and Run as administrator

Hope it helps.